# Save arraylist values in a function

Tags: java, arraylist

So I was trying to get the number of samples but everytime I call this function the available sample list resets due to `ArrayList<Sample> available = new ArrayList<Sample>(this.getSample());` So if I call another function that remove or add the sample then call this function it will always be the default plus or minus the size. For example....if `this.getSample()` size is 5 and there are 2 soils that aren't available. I call the remove function twice but my result will always end with 4 where it should be 3.

```
public ArrayList<Sample> getAvailableSample() {
    ArrayList<Sample> available = new ArrayList<Sample>(this.getSample());  
 //create a copy of arraylist from sample. (doesn't mess with original data)
        for(Sample s : available) {  //loop through list
            if(s.getSoil()!=null){ //soil is not available
            available.remove(s);   //remove from list
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("size of available: "+available.size());
        return available; //returns number of available samples
    }
```

I could not move the `ArrayList<Sample> available = new ArrayList<Sample>(this.getSample());` outside because `ArrayList<Sample>(this.getSample());` default is null and I cannot call this class's function without messing up other functions in this or other classes.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible by using `available` as the iterator, then using `remove` it's messing with the current position within the iterator (or worse breaking it).  Consider using `this.getSamples()` as the iterator instead, but still remove the values from `available`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping on `s`, but reading only `b`.

```
for(Sample s : available) {
    if(s.getSoil()!=null) {     // s, not b.
        available.remove(s);   // s, not b.
    }
}
```

You can read your loop like for each `Sample` s in `available`.

Create a `Collection c`, and then remove it after your loop.

```
List<Sample> c = new ArrayList<>();
for(Sample s : available) {
    if(s.getSoil()!=null) {
        c.add(s);
    }
}
available.removeAll(c);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been stuck in this since forever.

Answer (score 0):

I`m thinking that the problem is that you can`t delete an object that from a list that is being interated.

Can you try doing as below? Instead deleting the Sample that don`t have available soil you can create a new list with only the objects that have soil.

```
public ArrayList<Sample> getAvailableSample() {
    ArrayList<Sample> available = new ArrayList<Sample>();  
    for(Sample s : this.getSample()) {  //loop through list
        if(s.getSoil()==null){ //soil is available
          available.add(s);   //add into the available list
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("size of available: "+available.size());
    return available; //returns number of available samples
}
```